# What to do about troll users?

Tags: support

https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/9946/kittensatplay

Apparently this user was banned for a month and is now back and trolling anyone who tries to help them. They will delete their questions after a short exchange of unprofessional comments.

As an aside, if anyone else was interested, there is a [GreaseMonkey script](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3360/ignore-users-script) for ignoring people on StackExchange. Could save some gray hairs anyways.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What to do about trolls and other miscreants?  **Flag their posts.**  The first few flags alert moderators; the accumulation of flags provides both an incentive for the mods to act as well as documentation to support their actions.

In response to a one-year suspension (which is rare on SE and unprecedented here on GIS) one user recently wrote back to the moderators to exclaim that

> you improve by banning

[they meant "suspending," because although one year may be a long time on the Web, it is not banishment].

Yes, indeed, I think we can all agree the suspension was an improvement.  The system works :-).

Answer (score 3):

Repeated breach of protocol ID FAQ#etiquette detected. Beep zip beep. Initialize termination sequence.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, the best way to deal with those people is to **ignore** them. I would not dare spending my time with answering in any way. Besides, what do you expect of someone with such a user nick?

For the gray hair: Too late for me ;-)

Comment: But, in passing, please take a second to flag offensive posts.

Comment: Ok, but not much more...

Answer (score 0):

Yes but if you ignore them, questions still pop up and stay there. How about: automatically remove questions from users with < 10 reputation, which have  <= 0 vote, maybe less than that many views after 1 week?

Comment: I suggest to let that do by Community bot, after a month or when he passes by first.